# Convert Spanned Dynamic disk to Basic Help needed

Tags: windows-server-2008, diskmanagement

Here is my scenario; Windows 2008 server on a VM Two VM disks; Disk1 > OS >Basic Disk2> Data and an Installed Application.> Basic

During the weekend, I was playing with this VM, I wanted to add some space to the Disk2. Created a new disk (disk3), converted it to a Dynamic volume and added this to disk 2 (disk 2 also converted to Dynamic volume) and for some reason these now are spanned volumes. Just like an IDIOT, I haven't taken any snapshot of this before I've made the changes. My question, is there a way I can re-convert this again to Basic? I don't want to delete and recreate the disk volumes because of the application installed on the disk 2

Any solution or tips I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only microsoft default tools the only way to convert back is to [backup and restore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776315(WS.10).aspx)

There are ways to convert single dynamic disks but spanned disks really need to be recreated.

Comment: Thanls for your reply,
I was wondering if using a type of cloning, imaging based application to take an image of this spanned disks, will it affect the destination disk?( Reg keys, Sys files and file Ids??

Comment: any sort of imaging is going to take a copy of the partition table, which puts you back at square 1

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert a dynamic disk to a basic one in disk management unless you delete all the partitions on it.

Since you don't want lose the data, reconverting is not the only solution.

You can copy the data to a new basic disk (it must be unallocated space of a basic disk), then everything is settled.

Recommended tool:

http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/clone-dynamic-disk.htm